# Запятая перед "и", будет ли ошибкой если поставить?

Tags: пунктуация

1 Этаж - приточные системы в детскую игровую и гостиную комнаты:

Comment: С какой целью ставить? Вот в вопросе перед  е с л и  надо, а после «и» — нет.

Comment: Если вам дан хороший ответ, отметьте его галочкой.

Comment: Вероятно, имеется в виду первый этаж; тогда нужно писать "1-й этаж" (с буквенным наращением после цифры и  строчной *э*)

Comment: По-моему, нужно писать не "системы в комнаты", а "системы для комнат"

Answer (score 1):

Вообще, непонятно, что значит «приточный» в вашем предложении, но тем не менее совершенно ясно: запятой перед *и* быть не может — она соединяет однородные определения.

Comment: Вероятно, речь идет о системах приточной вентиляции квартир.